# How to fix list brackets for list of coordinates

Tags: python, coordinates, polyline-creation, list, dictionary

I am trying to populate an empty list with pairs of coordinates taken from a dictionary of pairs of coordinates.

Here is my code that is creating this list:

```
        #Skip shorter rows
            if len(row) < 13:
                next(csvReader)

            else:
                lat = float(row[latIndex])
                lon = float(row[lonIndex])
                lap = float(row[lapIndex])
                
                vertices.append([lon, lat])
                if lap in verticesDict:
                    verticesDict[int(lap)].append([lon, lat])
                else:
                    verticesDict[int(lap)] = [lon, lat]
                    
        keyVertices = []
        
        keyVertices.append(verticesDict[0])
```

Something is going wrong with the list creation, because the resulting list (keyVertices) looks like this at the beginning:

```
[[149.6849218, -34.8394436, [149.6849218, -34.8394436], [149.6849218, -34.8394436],
```

The first pair of coordinates only has the opening [ bracket, and does not have one after the second coordinate value where it should be:

```
[[149.6849218, -34.8394436,
```

The end of the list also looks like this:

```
 [149.6851766, -34.8405473]]]
```

It has a third ] bracket that should be enclosing the first pair of coordinates above. What can I do to fix this?

For the list to be readable I need the first coordinate pair to be correctly enclosed with [] brackets.

Comment: Python's just doing what you asked (initializing the array to `lon, lat`, then adding two-vertex lists thereafter). You probably wanted to initialize with `verticesDict[int(lap)] = [[lon, lat]]` But it would have been better to alter the original Question to focus on this detail, rather than creating this duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading Geometry Sequence when writing polylines to shapefile gives TypeError](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445402/reading-geometry-sequence-when-writing-polylines-to-shapefile-gives-typeerror)

Comment: @Vince Firstly sorry for the duplicate, I'm brand new here. Secondly, do you know of a way I can populate the dictionary so that the first coordinate pair is properly enclosed with brackets?

Comment: I edited the comment to include that a few minutes ago.

Comment: @Vince That worked. Thanks very much, you're a lifesaver. Also, I feel a little foolish for missing it!